# New ElasticSearch 5.2.1 Install on Ubuntu 16.04: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I just followed this install guide for Elasticsearch via APT:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/deb.html

When I run `curl -X GET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/'` (or localhost) I receive an error: `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused`

In my configuration, I'm using:

```
network.bind_host: localhost
network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

My log at `/var/log/elasticsearch/` is blank, but looking at `sudo journalctl --unit elasticsearch` I see:

```
Starting Elasticsearch...
Started Elasticsearch.
elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Starting Elasticsearch...
Started Elasticsearch.
elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Starting Elasticsearch...
Started Elasticsearch.
elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
...
```

How can I track down the holdup in getting this service online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

undo your configuration changes and service should start:

- `bind_host` is defaults to `network.host` (in your case it's `0.0.0.0`), yet you're forcing to `localhost`? (0.0.0.0 != localhost)
- `network.host` - for security reason, I wouldn't set to `0.0.0.0` (default: `127.0.0.1`)
- `http.port` - is set to 9200 by default.

Comment: I switched from a t2.small (2GB ram) to a t2.medium (4Gb RAM) EC2 server and this seemed to get it up and running.  It looks like elasticsearch wants to see *64Gb*

Comment: @arby: BTW, Elasticsearch could start at 2Gb of RAM
check /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options file and change default values to: -Xms2g -Xmx2g